# Processing loadStrings strings are always different, even if seemingly equal

Tags: arrays, string, processing

In Processing I've been trying to read from a text file which contains different strings. When read by Processing with the saveStrings function and compared, they are always different, even if the lines seem to be equal in the get file. I've recently tried writing to the text file with saveStrings, but that doesn't work either.

```java
    String lines[] = loadStrings("list.txt");
    String list[] = {"1", "1"};

    void test() {
      saveStrings("data/list.txt", list);
      println(lines[0] == lines[1]); //returns false
      println("1" == "1");           //returns true
    }
```

I just call the method in the setup function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare `String` values. Use the `equals()` function instead:

```
 println(lines[0].equals(lines[1]));
```

You need to do this because `==` compares whether two `String` values are the same object. The **literal** `"1"` is equal to itself, so it evaluates to `true`. However, two `String` values you read in from a file are not the same object, so `==` evaluates to `false` then.

The `equals()` function actually checks the characters inside of the `String` values and returns `true` if they both contain the same characters.

This is also covered in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/String.html):

> To compare the contents of two Strings, use the equals() method, as in if (a.equals(b)), instead of if (a == b). A String is an Object, so comparing them with the == operator only compares whether both Strings are stored in the same memory location. Using the equals() method will ensure that the actual contents are compared. (The [troubleshooting reference](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Troubleshooting#Why_don.27t_these_Strings_equal.3F) has a longer explanation.)